# Upload File using a form in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to upload files to a folder called uploads in my wordpress theme. But it is not uploading the files. Can anybody please help , below is my code

HTML Code

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

[upload]

Below is php code of shortcode in functions.php file

```
functions upload ()
{
$file = $_FILES['file'];
$name = $file['name'];
$path = "/uploads/" . basename($name);
if (move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $path)) {
    echo " Move succeed";
} else {
 echo " Move failed. Possible duplicate?";
}
}

add_shortcode('upload','upload');
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

try to use this function .Define this in your `function.php`

```
<?php
function upload_user_file( $file = array() ) {

    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/admin.php' );

      $file_return = wp_handle_upload( $file, array('test_form' => false ) );

      if( isset( $file_return['error'] ) || isset( $file_return['upload_error_handler'] ) ) {
          return false;
      } else {

          $filename = $file_return['file'];

          $attachment = array(
              'post_mime_type' => $file_return['type'],
              'post_title' => preg_replace( '/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename( $filename ) ),
              'post_content' => '',
              'post_status' => 'inherit',
              'guid' => $file_return['url']
          );

          $attachment_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $file_return['url'] );

          require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');
          $attachment_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attachment_id, $filename );
          wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attachment_id, $attachment_data );

          if( 0 < intval( $attachment_id ) ) {
            return $attachment_id;
          }
      }

      return false;
}
?>
```

and use like this

```
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['upload']))
    {
       if( ! empty( $_FILES ) ) 
       {
          $file=$_FILES['file'];
          $attachment_id = upload_user_file( $file );

       }
    }
    ?>

<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file">
    <input type="submit" name="upload">
</form>
```

Comment: thanks but how will this function run in functions.php file ... we have not used any function call or can I use a shortcode please guide and also kindly note that there is a custom folder not the wordpress folder where I want to upload file ... thanks

Comment: why you want to use shortcode ?? and you will get attachment id you can get image through attachment id of any size you want . and we call this function on the page where the form exists.

Comment: Infact I am creating an image upload competition functionality where users can upload images and others can rate and their will be a winner who has the most votes. So how can I upload to a custom folder other then the default upload folder

Comment: There is a tiny error in the script: 

$attachment_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $file_return['url'] );

should be: 
$attachment_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $file_return['file'] );

Comment: You saved the day buddy. Thanks for sharing :)

Answer (score 3):

if you want to upload in a custom folder you can use this function

add the function in `functions.php`

```
function upload_user_file( $file = array(),$path ) {
    if(!empty($file)) 
    {


        $upload_dir=$path;
        $uploaded=move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $upload_dir.$file['name']);
        if($uploaded) 
        {
            echo "uploaded successfully ";

        }else
        {
            echo "some error in upload " ;print_r($file['error']);  
        }
    }

}
```

make a form in your `template file` like this

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file">
    <input type="submit" name="upload">
</form>
```

call the upload function in template file like before `get_header();` function

```
if(isset($_POST['upload']))
    {

       if( ! empty( $_FILES ) ) 
       {
          $file=$_FILES['file'];   // file array
          $upload_dir=wp_upload_dir();
          $path=$upload_dir['basedir'].'/myuploads/';  //upload dir.
          if(!is_dir($path)) { mkdir($path); }
          $attachment_id = upload_user_file( $file ,$path);

       }
    }
```

Comment: i know this old, but how would you echo the image path after uploading?

Comment: 5 years later. I'm still waiting for an answer for the question @730wavy brought up.